Simplest Peltier Control
I wish to control the delta-T across a Peltier module using constant voltage and variable current.  If efficiency is not an issue, can I just wire a potentiometer in parallel with the module? I realize I may have to provide heat sinks for both the module and the resistor.
If this is possible, how do I size the pot?

How big/small of a Peltier are we talking and what size potentiometer?

Putting a potentiometer in parallel with the load will not do anything if you have a constant voltage power supply. You'd use parallel with constant current and series for constant voltage.

Your approach with the potentiometer for even the smallest TEC is a terrible approach. The simplest solution would be to use an bench top adjustable power supply.

Can you specify the supply voltage, min and max current?

@user1850479 -Putting a potentiometer in parallel with the load will not do anything- Well, it might generate some extra heat ;)

Thanks for the responses.  I just need a cheap way to adjust the current so I can keep the hot side from overheating.  I am using 2 or 3 TEC1-12715 units in parallel and have water pumped heat exchangers on both sides to mediate the temperature, but I am guessing the hot side is the only one to worry about.  I have an engineering background (mechanical), but electronics was obviously never my strong suit.  Right now I am using a 12v LED power supply.  I have ordered a voltage and current adjustable power supply, but I was hoping to get my experiment running before it arrives.  Thanks again.

I am shooting for 12V as the power supplies are easy to get.  TI has an article that says using a resistor to limit current and control delta T is not efficient, but an option.  I just don't know where to put the resistor and would like adjustability, thus the pot.

Put two TEC1-12715 units in series. This will reduce the total power to 25% of the parallel combination while still giving you substantial cooling for testing purposes.

But I want more than 25% of the power... okay, I can give it a try.

I would like to phrase this another way.  If I have a 12V power supply that provides 100A, how can I regulate the current to the device.  I wish to avoid PWM.
